# Check that all rows match a given criterion

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
requestId   Consultantid  statusid
1           2             10
2           2             10
3           2             10
```

I want to check if every row has a statusid of 10.

```
if (every row has a statusid of 10) then
  -----do this
endif;
```

Comment: i want to check that all the statusid values must be equal to 10 if a single statusid value is not 10 then condition should return false

Comment: @secko :-i dont want to check any one ,i want to check every field of statusid =10

Comment: select *
from blablabla_table
where
if(statusid = 10) then 
something, something 
else
return false
end if;

Comment: You got some nice answers, check them! Also check, http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0440__PL-SQL-Statements/IFELSEstatements.htm

Comment: @ Welbog ...let me try..
tnks  Welbog,Secko

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rusty on PL-SQL, but something like this would work in T-SQL:

```
 if not exists (select * from your_table where statusid <> 10) then
    -- whatever
 end
```

**Edit:**
Ok, apparantly in PL-SQL, you need to do something like this:

```
DECLARE
  notallten INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO notallten 
  FROM your_table
  WHERE statusid <> 10
  AND ROWNUM = 1;
  IF notallten = 0 THEN
    -- Do something
  END IF;
END;
```

I don't have an Oracle server to test on though.

Comment: This works in SQL Server, but not in Oracle PL/SQL, it cannot be mixed like that. SQL cannot handle boolean variables.

Comment: Why is ROWNUM needed in this at all?  It looks good without that.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
v_exists_status_10 number(1);
...

begin
...
-- v_exists_status_10 = 0 if no such row exist, 1 if at least one does
select count(*)
into   v_exists_status_10
from   dual
where  exists
  (select * from your_table where statusid <> 10);

if v_exists_status_10 > 0 then
...
```

Note that you could also do a dumb COUNT(*) into a variable, but it could be massively inefficient compared to EXISTS. With a COUNT(*) you'd have to scan all the records, whereas with an EXISTS as soon as it hits a statusid = 10 it can stop scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution, that accounts for NULLs in statusid:

```
for r in (
  select 1 dummy
  from   your_table
  where  (statusid != 10 or statusid is null)
  and    rownum = 1) loop
    -----do this
end loop;
```